# Rails - create a record with nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm receiving a request in the format:

```json
{
  recipe_translations: [{
      "lang": "en",
      "name": "wow",
      "value": "test"
    }]
}
```

The `Recipe`:

```rb
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recipe_translations, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipe_translations
end
```

The controller:

```rb
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
  end

  def recipe_params
    # whitelist params
    params.permit(recipe_translations: %i[lang name value])
  end

end
```

Obviously, something is very wrong but not sure what. The error I'm getting is:

```
#<ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: RecipeTranslation(#69020) expected, got {\"lang\"=>\"en\", \"name\"=>\"wow\", \"value\"=>\"test\"} which is an instance of ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#52480)>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
def recipe_params
   params.fetch(:recipe_translations, {}).permit(%w[lang name value])
end
```